# ajax + php: не работает счетчик

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

первый скрипт подключает файл с js и выводит кнопку и счетчик:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="doWork" />
<div id="rate">0</div>
```

сам файл js:

```
function getHTTPObject(){
   if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
           else {
           alert("Ваш браузер не поддерживает AJAX.");
           return null;
           }
   }

function setOutput(){
    if (httpObject.readyState == 4){
           document.getElementById('rate').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
    }

}

function doWork(){    
     httpObject = getHTTPObject();

     if (httpObject != null) {
        httpObject.open("GET", "2.php?rate="
            +document.getElementById('rate').innerHTML, true);
        httpObject.send(); 
    httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput();
      }
  }

 var httpObject = null;
```

и сам скрипт увеличения:

```
echo ($_GET['rate']+1);
```

кто разбирается в js скажите что не так, ибо ничего не работает.

ps
брал отсюда: http://www.vr-online.ru/content/ajax-php-povyshaem-interaktivnost-1864

**еще вопрос по улучшению скрипта:**
если я хочу в кнопке передать параметы, вот такие изменния корректы будут:

```
<input type="button" onclick="doWork('rate','rate','rate')" />
```

где 1 параметр - передаваемая переменная GET, 2й - откуда брать значение, 3й - куда записывать. И соотв. js код:

```
function doWork(p1,p2,p3){
...
httpObject.open("GET", "2.php?"+p1+"="+document.getElementById(p2).innerHTML, true); 
...
httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput(p3);
}
function setOutput(p){
   if (httpObject.readyState == 4){
       document.getElementById(p).innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
}
```

Такой скрипт будет корректен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ибо ничего не работает.

:D это очень информативное описание ошибки....

1. Загляните в консоль javfascript проверьте ошибки.
2. нужно писать так:
       httpObject.open("GET", "2.php", true);
       httpObject.send("rate="+document.getElementById('rate').innerHTML);

3.

httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput();

заменить на:

httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;

1. в функции setOutput httpobject должен приходить в параметрах.

Comment: 1)консоль ошибок оперы: ничего нет (:
2)исправил
3)убрал скобки
А что за параметры должны приходить? можно подробнее?
уже при выполнении пункта 3 заработало.

Answer (score 1):

1) Назначение функции обработчика "setOutput", необходимо указывать до отправки. Т.е. вот так:
httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
httpObject.send();

2) httpObject.open("GET", "2.php", true);
3-ий параметр "true" устанавливает выполнение асинхронного AJAX запроса. Т.е, после отправки "httpObject.send();" скрипт продолжит свое выполнение, и не будет дожидаться AJAX ответов.

3) httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
указывается без скобок, т.к. здесь в свойство "onreadystatechange" объекта "httpObject" передается хэш функции, что бы ее вызвать позже. Если указать "setOutput();" то сразу же будет вызвана эта функции и в свойство "onreadystatechange" запишется ее результат выполнения.

Comment: а вообще как-нибудь в setOutput можно передать параметр?

Comment: можно. есть различные подходы для этого. Но это тема другого вопроса.

Comment: я просто создал целую функцию для выполнения всех дейсвий, и setOutput уже идет как подфункция - так и передаю параметры.

Comment: Если вам нужно передавать параметры, вместо:

      =setOutput; 

      // надо

      =function() {  setOutput(p1,p2)  }

Comment: это плохой вариант, связанный с глобальными переменными и ссылками на них, очень легко можно запутаться. Лучше использовать так называемый бинд аргументов.

Comment: var p1, p2;
    // ... code
    =function(){
        // тут мы можем использовать p1, p2
    }

Типа так? Не хотел усложнять, по поводу отладки - я себе представляю какой ужас вы отлаживали если подобная запись каким-то образом влияла на проблему глобальности, хотя я и согласен что этот способо лучше - многие его не понимают и, в процессе разработки, возникает **гораздо больше** проблем

**жажду** кусок кода где описаный выше способ вызывает проблемы с глобальной областью видимости

И если скрипт работает неправильно - значит ошибка в первую очередь - в **логике**, или вы так не считаете?

Comment: К сожалению var тут не поможет.


>>  я себе представляю какой ужас вы отлаживали если подобная запись каким-то образом влияла на проблему глобальности

Всё значительно банальней и проще, в основном проблемы с таким подходом возникают при асинхронной работе. (аякс, наш случай)

простенький пример (я думаю понятно, что ожидается 1,2,3 в консоле):

    function f1(num){ console.log(num); }
    function test()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            setTimeout(function () { f1(i); }, 1000 );
        }
    }

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к ajax'у и асинхронности?
****
Это азы которые должен знать любой разработчик, по этому подобного рода проблемы(да вообще - практически все проблемы), **как всегда** - возникают **исключительно** из-за незнания, неопытности или халатности разработчика. И от этого никого ничто не спасет.

Comment: Да, это очень простой пример, илюстрирующий как раз асинхронное выполнение кода. Поэтому я и говорю что этот вариант не сильно хорош в данном случае.

Comment: До этого был плохой, теперь уже не сильно хороший? :D

Comment: не придирайтесь к словам)

Comment: лично я просто сделал функцию, которую вызываю при онКлик, а в этой функции разместил все остальные функции. параметры передаю главной и все нормально работает

Comment: Это главное =)